# Why are final prices missing on larger product exports?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

The requirement is to fix the final price export in Magento 2.4.2. The issue is as follows:

We want to export product data into a CSV. We also want to export the final prices of the products. For that, an after Plugin is supposed to take the exported array and add an additional column for the final price before it gets handed to the file writing logic of the export.

The Plugin works as follows:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product as ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Firebear\ImportExport\Model\Export\Product as FirebearProduct;

class AfterGetExportDataPlugin
{
    public const FINAL_PRICE_EXPORT = 'export_finalPrice';

    private ResourceModel $resourceModel;

    private ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    private Price $price;

    public function __construct(
        ResourceModel $resourceModel,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Price $price
    ) {
        $this->resourceModel = $resourceModel;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * @param FirebearProduct $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterGetExportData(FirebearProduct $subject, array $result)
    {
        // Evaluate if final price is a selected attribute for the export
        $additionalColumns = $subject->getParameters()['list'];
        if (false === in_array(self::FINAL_PRICE_EXPORT, $additionalColumns, true)) {
            return $result;
        }

        // Evaluate if an alias for final price is set
        $exportAttributeMapping = self::FINAL_PRICE_EXPORT;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $additionalColumns; $i++) {
            if ($additionalColumns[$i] === self::FINAL_PRICE_EXPORT) {
                $exportAttributeMapping = $subject->getParameters()['replace_code'][$i];
                break 1;
            }
        }

        return array_map(function ($product) use ($exportAttributeMapping) {
            /** @var Product $productEntity */
            $productEntity = $this->productRepository->get((string) $product['sku']);
            $product[$exportAttributeMapping] = (float) $this->price->getFinalPrice(1, $productEntity);
            return $product;
        }, $result);
    }
}
```

I tested that with 5000 products on my development environment and the export went well. But when we exported 400000 products on our staging environment, the majority of final prices were missing.
I can't figure out why that is. Does anyone how or why that happens?

FYI: We use the Firebear export extension but I don't think it matters that much in this context.

Comment: What do you mean the prices were missing? Have you tried debugging step by step or at the very least logging/dumping info to a file throughout the after to see what's going on?

Comment: Many final prices were missing in the export (.csv) file. But not all of them. And what exactly is to log here? The final prices get written directly into the .csv file after the Plugin is finished. So the export is practically the log file. The big question is: Why are all final prices for products exported on my development environment when I export around 5000 products but they are missing on our testing environment when I export around 400000 products?